# pdf screenshot attachment mail

Tags: ios, pdf, screenshot, email-attachments

I have some problems to convert screenshot image from ipad to pdf, and attach it inside email. I can't understand where is the problem.

Someone can help me? Thanks a lot for help.

my debug area:

> 2013-10-14 12:28:20.056 emailallegato[1309:60b]
>   documentDirectoryFileName:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/F4BCEBFD-3684-45A4-8D78-D88ECA5E44F4/Documents/Test.pdf

this is my code:

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{

NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

[pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}

- (IBAction)iniva:(id)sender
{

[self createPDFfromUIView:self.view saveToDocumentsWithFileName:@"Test.pdf"];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

 if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

    [mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pdftest@gmail.com", nil]];
    [mail setSubject:@"Oggetto "];
    [mail setMessageBody:@"Messaggio e-mail" isHTML:NO];
    [mail addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"Material Details.pdf"];


    [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
 }}
```

Comment: Did you check that pdf is created successfully or not at Document directory

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.Yes I check... but it does't work. I modify the code and add a picture off my code.Could you take a look? thanks

Comment: ya sure.. can you provide me your code?

Comment: I modify the code inside my question; but if you want, I can share with you a dropbox's link with a part of my app, or I can send you a email.Thanks again for your kindness.

Comment: I find my error! Now the code works very well.I forget to implement NSMutableData *pdfData . Thanks again for your answer. bye

Comment: Can you vote up my answer?

Comment: Sorry.. my reputation is under 15, so I couldn't do that.When I go over I'll vote up your answer. thks

Comment: ok bro... no prob... enjoy coding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *fileName1;

fileName1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test.pdf"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *saveDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dataFilePath = [saveDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName1];

NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataFilePath];
```

Then attach this data

These are the useful links for pdf creation:

https://github.com/bygreencn/iPhonePDF

http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/

https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten

http://www.ioslearner.com/convert-html-uiwebview-pdf-iphone-ipad/